# I got MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error,How can resolve this issues

Tags: operating-system, windows-10, video-processing, moviepy, python-3.11

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, TextClip, 
CompositeVideoClip

os.environ["IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY"] = r"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI/magick.exe"

def create_video_with_typewriter_effect(text, output_filename, fontsize=30, video_fps=30):
 # Load your video
 video = VideoFileClip("D:/video.mp4")
 video = video.subclip(0, 2)  # Trim the video if needed

 # Get video dimensions
 video_width = video.w
 video_height = video.h
 video_size = (video_width, video_height)

 # Create a TextClip for the entire text
 font = 'Arial-Bold'
 text_clip = TextClip(text, fontsize=fontsize, font=font, color='white')

 # Calculate the number of frames for the typing effect
 num_frames = int(video.duration * video_fps)

 # Initialize a list to store each frame
 frames = []

 # Create individual frames for the typing effect
 for frame_idx in range(num_frames):
    frame = np.zeros((video_height, video_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    frame_pil = Image.fromarray(frame)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(frame_pil)

    current_text = text[:int(len(text) * frame_idx / num_frames)]
    text_clip = TextClip(current_text, fontsize=fontsize, font=font, color='white')
    text_clip = text_clip.set_duration(1 / video_fps)
    text_clip = text_clip.set_position(("center", "center"))
    text_clip = text_clip.set_start(frame_idx / video_fps)
    frames.append(text_clip.get_frame(frame_idx / video_fps))

# Composite the frames over the video
typewriter_video = CompositeVideoClip([video.set_duration(video.duration), *frames])

# Write the final video to the output file
typewriter_video.write_videofile(output_filename, codec='libx264', fps=video_fps)


text = "Ancient Ruins and Storied History Journey through Sri Lanka's Cultural Triangle"
output_filename = "D:/output_video.mp4"
create_video_with_typewriter_effect(text, output_filename)
```

Error that i got:
[image]
**OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:
convert.exe: label expected `@C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprpxltnkj.txt' @ error/annotate.c/GetMultilineTypeMetrics/804. convert.exe: no images defined` PNG32:C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaf7s7kpu.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3362.
.
.This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect**

Comment: Hey I checked your code, it is not actually the ImageMagick path, try changing the  text_clip = TextClip(current_text, fontsize=fontsize, font=font, color='white') to text_clip = TextClip('hello', fontsize=fontsize, font=font, color='white') The error changes

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, if you wanna create a typewriting effect I have the code here on my github https://github.com/mi1acl/typewriter-python

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that you have already installed the [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php). And you should also set the env for "IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY"

[image]

I tried setting IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY, but had the same problem. In the end, I had to modify the source code directly and hard-code this value.

Comment: Hi,I've already install imagemagick.but still same error.no changes

Comment: @MrDumb you can try the config showed in the picture. Change it with your image macgick's loction.